# Folders missing from mq client v8 installation

Tags: ibm-mq

Few folders(errors,exits,exits64,trace..),mqclient.ini are missing after installing mq v8 client on a 64 bit machine. And even logs/trace is not getting created. Did anyone experience this issue. I have tried to clean install couple of times and the same msi works fine on other machines
Below are the only folders installed

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They arent missing - in 7.1+ on windows, MQ will install the data path into c:\ProgramData\IBM, and the binaries into C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (or WebSphere MQ for pre-v9). The split was to enable multiple installation support, as they all share a single data directory. Note that C:\ProgramData is hidden - just type it into the explorer bar to go into it.

As to why you might not have seen this before - If you upgrade (or even uninstall / install) from pre-7.1 to post-7.1, then the data path will stay where it was and be unchangeable for server installs (if there are any queue managers left behind) or it may default to the previous location (so things like user exits, MQClient.ini configuration etc is not lost) but be changeable.